# Hide row by clicking on ActionLink in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I was wondering is there some way to hide one row if action link is clicked in MVC, but pass via action link anyway. I'm just trying to hide it on clients page.

Like here for example. When user click on Add Friend action link whole row will be hidden.
Should I do this with JavaScript for example?

[image]

This is my current view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DesignedAppNew.Models.UserProfile>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListAllFriends";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ID").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Add some new friends:</h2>

<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId) 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) 
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Friend", "AddNewFriend", new { id = "ID" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Yes, with `jQuery` you can get the closest `tr` and hide it.

Comment: yes you can do this with jquery..as shown..

Comment: if need more help then plzz comment!!...

Comment: Can you please show your view.

Comment: @Saranga Sure, I've just updated my post. :)

Comment: just try below answer it should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery for this as :-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".friend").click(function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").hide();
   });
});
```

In your update all actionlinks will have same id this is wrong do it as :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Friend", "AddNewFriend", null, new { @class="friend" })
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering this fast. I will try it right away :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot repeat ID in your HTML, Try this;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Friend", "AddNewFriend", null, new { @class = "addfriend" })

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addfriend").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm still not hiding <tr>'s ... Should I maybe import some special script? Or the one I've imported for jQuery is enough? @Saranga

Comment: You don't need anything other than jQuery, are you getting any console errors ? Do you want to go to `AddNewFriend` page when the link is clicked ?